# Odoo 9.0c - Can't find 'Modules' menu

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

My problem is that I can't find 'Modules' in my Settings (Odoo 9.0c).
I've already tried:

- switching to Developer Mode
- Enabling Technical Features
- checked the URL (web?debug=...)
- restarting the odoo server/service (even with odoo.py --update=all)

and it still looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUSjL.jpg). 
Do you have any idea what could cause this issue?

Thanks in adavance!

Cheers,
sBakos

Answer (score 0):

Ckick in X near Apps (screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZK02.jpg) and you will see all modules (screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8X1d.jpg )

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got all the modules now.
Is there a way to enable custome modules tho?
Can't seem to find my own.

Comment: When you upload your custome module on server you need to change Chmod for user and group which use odoo.

Comment: (upsss i click send and i cant edit previous comment ;/)

Comment: When you do this, next in Apps in debug mode you need to click "Update Apps list". When you do this, app will show on modules list.